# KeystoneJS: Cors issue

Tags: keystonejs

i want to enable the CORS. so I set the keystone.set('cors allow origin', true); 
and have this in my router:
app.all('/api*', keystone.middleware.cors);

but it doesn't work.

I have to change  createDynamicRouter in keystone/lib and add this in

```
router.all('/api*', function (req, res, next) {
console.log('------------------------------------------------');
console.log('Notice: Enabling CORS headers.');
console.log('------------------------------------------------');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
next();
});
```

i created a model and using the auto-created routers.

did I do something wrong? I want to enable cors in my code, not in the keystone core code.

thanks.
mikeso

Answer (score 0):

[This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/619) may be of use to you. Namely, you may need to add this code to your `routes/index.js` file:

```
app.all('/api*', keystone.middleware.cors);
app.options('/api*', function(req, res) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
   res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I added above code in my router but it doesn't work. i have a model list and the router of this model API are auto generated by the keystone JS core. but if i add above code to createDynamicRouter.js, it works. I am not sure what I did wrong